# Type mismatch with glLightfv

Tags: opengl

I have configured the OpenGL environment under windows, I use VS2010.

When I wrote this code: `glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 1.5)`, I got a **warning type mismatch** message.

I also got this informations:

> IntelliSense, "double type" real participation "const GLfloat *" type
>   parameter is not compatible with f: \ lirui \ project \ opengltest \
>   opengltest \ opengltest 22 50 opengltest CPP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `1.5` is of type **double** while [glLightfv](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glLight.xml) needs a **`const GLfloat *`**.

When you specify *pname* to be `GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION`, the documentation says:

> params is a single integer or floating-point value...

So you should use **`glLightf`** (or `glLighti`) instead of **`glLightfv`**.

You may give it a **float** (or an integer) instead of a **double** to avoid unnecessary cast:

```
glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 1.5);  // what you want
glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 1.5f); // what you want (avoid a cast)
glLighti(GL_LIGHT1, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 1);    // what you may want
```

Comment: For `glLightf` is does not really matter what OP uses, `float`, `double` or `int`. `glLightf(..., 1.0f);`, `glLightf(..., 1.0);` and `glLightf(..., 1);` will produce same results.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, My bad. C# habits.

Comment: it‘s my fault，I wrote glLightfv rather than glLightf，thanks a lot@Orace